# Cas Authentication Filter redirects response with Http instead of Https

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-security, java-11, cas

We are working on an application which has CAS implemented. The application works with https protocol and authenticates successfully. But when browser sends the request to backend with CAS ticket, server responds with http redirect instead of https.

Cas(org.springframework.security.cas) version used = 3.6.1

Below is the xml file for cas.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    
    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="https://dev.examples.com:9100/somepath/login/cas"/>
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
          class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://dev.examples.com:9000/cassso"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="key" value="cas_id"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl" value="https://dev.examples.com:9000/cassso/login"/>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:headers disabled="true"/>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied.xhtml"/>
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter"/>

        
        
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <!-- Logout -->
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="${cas.server.web.url}/logout"/>
    </security:http>

</beans>
```

When user successfully authenticates, browser redirects to service url with the service ticket. Below is the url to which browser redirected.

```
https://dev.examples.com:9100/somepath/login/cas?ticket=ST-1384-bjPrwEOI6JbseqRVC6eb-cas
```

Cas Authentication filter user this ticket to validate and responds back. But here is where i am facing the redirection issue as shown in the below image. In the response headers(from the image), location field has http, though the request was being sent as https.

[click to see the response of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOmPR.png)

I tried implementing a filter to force redirect response to https if its http, but no luck.

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HttpsRedirectFilter implements Filter
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HttpsRedirectFilter.class);


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        String getProtocol = req.getScheme();
        String getDomain = req.getServerName();
        String getPort = Integer.toString(req.getServerPort());
        String getQueryString = req.getQueryString();

        if (getProtocol.toLowerCase().equals("http")) {
            // New location to be redirected
            String httpsPath = "https" + "://" + getDomain + ":" + getPort + uri;
            if(!getQueryString.isEmpty() || getQueryString != null) {
                httpsPath = httpsPath + "?" + getQueryString;
            }
            //redirect
            res.sendRedirect(httpsPath);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: im facing the same issue, have you managed to find a workaround / solution?